# excel data validation error

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I'm trying to write a data validation list when it adds a new row how I keep getting run time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.

Been searching through here and trying out different codes that I could get my hands on but all seems to give me the same error.

I did managed to get it working previously but not sure why it is not working now.

Below is the code for the sub that works except for the data validation part.

```
Sub AddNewRecord()
Dim vNewRow As Long

' Find the first empty row in the data table
vNewRow = DataTable.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

' Check for data in Field 1
If Trim(Range("formField1").Value) = "" Then
    Range("formField1").Activate
    MsgBox "Please enter data in Field 1!"
    Exit Sub
End If
' Check for data in Field 2
If Trim(Range("formField2").Value) = "" Then
    Range("formField2").Activate
    MsgBox "Please enter data in Field 2!"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Copy the data to the data table
With DataTable
    .Cells(vNewRow, 1).Value = Range("formField1").Value
    .Cells(vNewRow, 2).Value = Range("formField2").Value
End With

' Add data validation to data table
With DataTable
    .Activate
    .Cells(vNewRow, 3).Select

    With Range("G" & vNewRow).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
             xlBetween, Formula1:="In Progress,Completed"
    End With

'        With Selection.Validation
'            .Delete
'            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
'            xlBetween, Formula1:="In Progress,Completed"
'            .IgnoreBlank = True
'            .InCellDropdown = True
'            .InputTitle = ""
'            .ErrorTitle = ""
'            .InputMessage = ""
'            .ErrorMessage = ""
'            .ShowInput = True
'            .ShowError = True
'        End With
End With

' Clear data fields and reset the form
With InputForm
    .Activate
    .Range("formField1").Value = ""
    .Range("formField2").Value = ""
    .Range("formField1").Select
    .Visible = False
End With
With DataTable
    .Activate
    .Cells(vNewRow, 1).Select
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: error stops at  .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
             xlBetween, Formula1:="In Progress,Completed"

Comment: any assistance on this error?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. My only thought is to try the `with Range("G" & vNewRow).Validation` block outside the `With DataTable` block.